# Как перейти по ссылке в коде на другую старницу

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Пишу расширение для хром, которое выделенный фрагмент текста со страницы помещает в Гуглшитс. Хочется после выбора  в контекстном меню перенаправить пользователя на лист гугл-шитс чтобы он увидел результаты. Имеется такой рабочий код background.js (нужно только реализовать переход на лист после исполнения кода):

```
function OrderToSupplier(info, tab) {

var sku = info['selectionText']
var orderurl = info['pageUrl']

var url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/{script ID}/dev?ssId={SSID}&sheetName=1&sku=" + sku + "&orderurl=" + orderurl;
console.log(url)    
fetch(url, {mode: 'no-cors'})
        .then(function(response) {                      
        console.log(response);
        setTimeout(linktoCRM, 10000,response['status'])
    })  
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log('Looks like there was a problem: \n', error);
    });
```

}

попытка перейти через функцию

```
function linktoCRM(respovsestatus){ 
if (respovsestatus == 200) {location.href = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{SSID}/edit#gid=0'}
```

}

результата не дает.

Comment: Скорее всего ты просто забыл дописать `window`

Твой код должен выглядеть так: 
`window.location.href = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{SSID}/edit#gid=0'}`

Comment: franmag Спасибо! Но в консоль прилетело опять: Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received

Comment: Вполне возможно, что проблема возникла из-за расширений хрома. Попробуй в другом браузере или отключи расширения.

Comment: franmag  - отключил все расширения, но при переходе по ссылке получаю вот такие ошибки 6 шт: GET chrome-extension://invalid/ net::ERR_FAILED. Причем ошибки идут на странице гугл шитс, конкретного листа куда пытаемся перейти. На самом деле мне нужно не перейти  по ссылке, а активировать уже открытую вкладку в хроме.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все оказалось просто, вот рабочий код:

```
function linktoCRM(responseStatus){ 
if (responseStatus == 200) { // если статус ответа положительный, тогда переходим на вкладку гуглШитс
    chrome.tabs.query({url:'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{SSID}/edit*',active: false,currentWindow: true}, function (tabs) { //Находи по url вкладку, куда будем переходить
    if (typeof tabs[0] == 'undefined')chrome.tabs.create({"url": "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{SSID}/edit#gid=0"}) // если найдена хоть одна вкладка переходим на первую вкладку 
    else chrome.tabs.update(tabs[0]['id'], {highlighted: true}) // если не одна вкладка не найдена открываем ее по url
```

});

Обратите внимание: вкладка не ищется по полному url гуглшита, его пришлось обрезать стоит в конце звезда. Почему - не знаю, но так работает.